# Commons Logging - ClassNotFoundException

Tags: apache

For whatever reason I can't seem to run my jar file without receiving a ClassNotFound Exception. I am new to Maven, so I believe the issue could be caused by my POM.XML file. Allow me to elaborate. I have isolated the problem to an example HelloWorld log.

```
package com;

import org.apache.commons.logging.Log;
import org.apache.commons.logging.LogFactory;

public class HelloLog {
   public static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(HelloLog.class);

   public static void main(String[] args){
       log.info("Hello World!");
   }
}
```

I have also simplified my pom.xml to only two dependencies.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>--MygroupId--</groupId>
  <artifactId>--MyArtID--</artifactId>
  <version>--MyVer--</version>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
      <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
      <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <resources>
      <resource>
        <directory>src</directory>
        <excludes>
          <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
        </excludes>
      </resource>
    </resources>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                 <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>lib</classpathPrefix>
                    <mainClass>com.HelloLog</mainClass>
                 </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
              <verbose>true</verbose>
              <fork>true</fork>
              <compilerVersion>1.6</compilerVersion>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
          <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <outputDirectory>
                                  ${project.build.directory}/dependency-jars/
                    </outputDirectory>
                    <overWriteReleases>false</overWriteReleases>
                    <overWriteSnapshots>false</overWriteSnapshots>
                    <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
    </plugins>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <!--This plugin's configuration is used to store Eclipse m2e settings only. It has no influence on the Maven build itself.-->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.m2e</groupId>
                <artifactId>lifecycle-mapping</artifactId>
                <version>1.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                        <pluginExecutions>
                            <pluginExecution>
                                <pluginExecutionFilter>
                                    <groupId>
                                        org.apache.maven.plugins
                                    </groupId>
                                    <artifactId>
                                        maven-dependency-plugin
                                    </artifactId>
                                    <versionRange>
                                        [2.5.1,)
                                    </versionRange>
                                    <goals>
                                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                                    </goals>
                                </pluginExecutionFilter>
                                <action>
                                    <ignore></ignore>
                                </action>
                            </pluginExecution>
                        </pluginExecutions>
                    </lifecycleMappingMetadata>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
  </build>
</project>
```

When I run the HelloLog class in Eclipse all is good and I get the expected output. However, when I execute java -jar on the Jar file I receive the ClasNotFoundException on LogFactory at line 7. The jar file is accompanied in the target folder with the dependency-jars folder. The dependency-jars folder holds these two dependencies.

Comment: Found problem, issue in the pom.xml ; specified different classpathPrefix when I copy the dependencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, it was Maven related. Hadn't noticed my classpathPrefix was set as lib. Where as I outputted the dependencies to dependency-jars.